# Doctrine query to search entities based on related entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've ManyToOne relationship in doctrine (Many results to One PollingStation):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2", inversedBy="results", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Expose
 */
 private $pollingStation2;
```

I'd like search for all the result that belong to the polling Station that have a name similar to a key word. I try the following method but it does not work:

```
public function getForSearch($keyWord)
{
    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->select('r')
        ->from('IballotCmsBundle:Result', 'r')
        ->where($query->expr()->like('p.pollingStation2', $query->expr()->literal('%' . $keyWord . '%')))
        //->orderBy('p.', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setParameter('keyWord', '%'.$keyWord.'%');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I get the following error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 48 near 'pollingStation2': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: ->leftJoin(r.pollingStations2,'p') Your order by also has a problem.  Getting ready for Super Tuesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Cerad (one more time), you need a `JOIN` to make the associated entity available while building your query.

Try this :

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$query
    ->select('r')
    ->from('IballotCmsBundle:Result', 'r')
    ->leftJoin('r.pollingStation2', 'p') // The missing join
    ->where('p.name LIKE :keyword') // where p.name like %keyword% 
    ->setParameter('keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC') // order by p.name ASC
    ->getQuery()

return $query->getResult();
```

BTW I fixed your `orderBy`, simplified your `where` and fixed the `keyword` parameter that is wrongly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this method in your Result EntityRepository class:

```
public function getForSearch($keyWord)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $query
        ->join('r.pollingStation2', 'p')
        ->where('p.name LIKE :keyword')
        ->setParameter('keyword', '%' . $keyWord . '%')
        //->orderBy('p.', 'ASC')
    ;
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```